# Why is my static dictionary not initialising?

Tags: c#

I am using a big dictionary I want to only be created once to store some information along with a static function to extract info from it like so:

```
public static class AceMimeInfo
{
    static Dictionary<string, Info> mimedictionary = new Dictionary<string, Info>
    {
        {".abap", new Info("abap", "ABAP")},
        {".asciidoc", new Info("asciidoc", "AsciiDoc")},
        {".c9search_results", new Info("c9search", "C9Search")},
        {".coffee", new Info("coffee", "CoffeeScript")},
        {".cf", new Info("coffee", "CoffeeScript")},
        {".xul", new Info("xml", "XML")},
        {".xbl", new Info("xml", "XML")},
        {".xq", new Info("xquery", "XQuery")},
        {".yaml", new Info("yaml", "YAML")}
    };

    public class Info
    {
        public string Mode;
        public string Name;

        public Info(string mode, string name)
        {
            Mode = mode;
            Name = name;
        }
    }

    public static string GetMode(string fileext)
    {
        string fe;

        fe = fileext.ToLower();
        if(!fe.StartsWith("."))
            fe = "." + fe;

        if (mimedictionary.ContainsKey(fe))
            return mimedictionary[fe].Mode;
        return "";
    }
}
```

However when I step through `GetMode` with the debugger, the dictionary `mimedictionary` is always null. 
What do I need to do to make sure this isn't the case?
Any suggestions as to a better way of doing this would also be appreciated.

I am calling `GetMode` this like so:

```
string mode = AceMimeInfo.GetMode("filename.cpp");
```

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

I tried the above code and it does indeed work. The dictionary above is a shorter version of what I am actually using (because it's quite long).

Here is the actual class I am using - and it doesn't work. When I shorten the dictionary, it does work.

```
public static class AceMimeInfo
{
    static Dictionary<string, Info> mimedictionary = new Dictionary<string, Info>
    {
        {".abap", new Info("abap", "ABAP")},
        {".asciidoc", new Info("asciidoc", "AsciiDoc")},
        {".c9search_results", new Info("c9search", "C9Search")},
        {".coffee", new Info("coffee", "CoffeeScript")},
        {".cf", new Info("coffee", "CoffeeScript")},
        {".cfm", new Info("coldfusion", "ColdFusion")},
        {".cs", new Info("csharp", "C#")},
        {".css", new Info("css", "CSS")},
        {".dart", new Info("dart", "Dart")},
        {".diff", new Info("diff", "Diff")},
        {".patch", new Info("diff", "Diff")},
        {".dot", new Info("dot", "Dot")},
        {".glsl", new Info("glsl", "Glsl")},
        {".frag", new Info("glsl", "Glsl")},
        {".vert", new Info("glsl", "Glsl")},
        {".go", new Info("golang", "Go")},
        {".groovy", new Info("groovy", "Groovy")},
        {".hx", new Info("haxe", "Haxe")},
        {".haml", new Info("haml", "HAML")},
        {".htm", new Info("html", "HTML")},
        {".html", new Info("html", "HTML")},
        {".xhtml", new Info("html", "HTML")},
        {".c", new Info("c_cpp", "C/C++")},
        {".cc", new Info("c_cpp", "C/C++")},
        {".cpp", new Info("c_cpp", "C/C++")},
        {".cxx", new Info("c_cpp", "C/C++")},
        {".h", new Info("c_cpp", "C/C++")},
        {".hh", new Info("c_cpp", "C/C++")},
        {".hpp", new Info("c_cpp", "C/C++")},
        {".clj", new Info("clojure", "Clojure")},
        {".jade", new Info("jade", "Jade")},
        {".java", new Info("java", "Java")},
        {".jsp", new Info("jsp", "JSP")},
        {".js", new Info("javascript", "JavaScript")},
        {".json", new Info("json", "JSON")},
        {".jsx", new Info("jsx", "JSX")},
        {".latex", new Info("latex", "LaTeX")},
        {".tex", new Info("latex", "LaTeX")},
        {".ltx", new Info("latex", "LaTeX")},
        {".bib", new Info("latex", "LaTeX")},
        {".less", new Info("less", "LESS")},
        {".lisp", new Info("lisp", "Lisp")},
        {".scm", new Info("lisp", "Lisp")},
        {".rkt", new Info("lisp", "Lisp")},
        {".liquid", new Info("liquid", "Liquid")},
        {".lua", new Info("lua", "Lua")},
        {".lp", new Info("luapage", "LuaPage")},
        {".lucene", new Info("lucene", "Lucene")},
        {".make", new Info("makefile", "Makefile")},
        {".md", new Info("markdown", "Markdown")},
        {".markdown", new Info("markdown", "Markdown")},
        {".m", new Info("objectivec", "Objective-C")},
        {".ml", new Info("ocaml", "OCaml")},
        {".mli", new Info("ocaml", "OCaml")},
        {".pl", new Info("perl", "Perl")},
        {".pm", new Info("perl", "Perl")},
        {".pgsql", new Info("pgsql", "pgSQL")},
        {".php", new Info("php", "PHP")},
        {".phtml", new Info("php", "PHP")},
        {".ps1", new Info("powershell", "Powershell")},
        {".py", new Info("python", "Python")},
        {".r", new Info("r", "R")},
        {".Rd", new Info("rdoc", "RDoc")},
        {".Rhtml", new Info("rhtml", "RHTML")},
        {".ru", new Info("ruby", "Ruby")},
        {".gemspec", new Info("ruby", "Ruby")},
        {".rake", new Info("ruby", "Ruby")},
        {".rb", new Info("ruby", "Ruby")},
        {".scad", new Info("scad", "OpenSCAD")},
        {".scala", new Info("scala", "Scala")},
        {".scss", new Info("scss", "SCSS")},
        {".sass", new Info("scss", "SCSS")},
        {".sh", new Info("sh", "SH")},
        {".bash", new Info("sh", "SH")},
        {".bat", new Info("sh", "SH")},
        {".sql", new Info("sql", "SQL")},
        {".styl", new Info("stylus", "Stylus")},
        {".stylus", new Info("stylus", "Stylus")},
        {".svg", new Info("svg", "SVG")},
        {".tcl", new Info("tcl", "Tcl")},
        {".tex", new Info("tex", "Tex")},
        {".txt", new Info("text", "Text")},
        {".textile", new Info("textile", "Textile")},
        {".typescript", new Info("typescript", "Typescript")},
        {".ts", new Info("typescript", "Typescript")},
        {".str", new Info("typescript", "Typescript")},
        {".xml", new Info("xml", "XML")},
        {".rdf", new Info("xml", "XML")},
        {".rss", new Info("xml", "XML")},
        {".wsdl", new Info("xml", "XML")},
        {".xslt", new Info("xml", "XML")},
        {".atom", new Info("xml", "XML")},
        {".mathml", new Info("xml", "XML")},
        {".mml", new Info("xml", "XML")},
        {".xul", new Info("xml", "XML")},
        {".xbl", new Info("xml", "XML")},
        {".xq", new Info("xquery", "XQuery")},
        {".yaml", new Info("yaml", "YAML")}
    };

    public class Info
    {
        public string Mode;
        public string Name;

        public Info(string mode, string name)
        {
            Mode = mode;
            Name = name;
        }
    }

    public static string GetMode(string fileext)
    {
        string fe;

        fe = fileext.ToLower();
        if(!fe.StartsWith("."))
            fe = "." + fe;

        if (mimedictionary.ContainsKey(fe))
            return "ace/mode/" + mimedictionary[fe].Mode;
        return "";
    }
}
```

Debugger output:

`{"The type initializer for 'TestApp.AceMimeInfo' threw an exception."}`

**Update II:** Where's the repeated key?

Comment: I didn't even know you could initialize a dictionary like that

Comment: So far it looks like you can't :P

Comment: Your code should work just fine. There is something else what you don't show us which causes mimedictionary to be `null`.

Comment: Works on my machine (I changed the accessibility to public, and did AceMimeInfo.mimedictionary.Count)

Comment: Isn't this just a debugger artifact? I guess that when you access it in your code, it will be initialized.

Comment: How do you create an instance of `AceMimeInfo` how do you call `GetMode`? Can you post an usage example?

Comment: There is definitely something more going on here than is being demonstrated in the excerpt you've posted.  Copying what you've posted into a new project results in everything working exactly how I would expect it to.

Comment: I can step through this in the debugger (VS2010) and it works perfectly -- it's initialized, and NOT null.

Comment: @nemesv Okay I ballsed up this question, (edited) there `GetMode` is in fact static

Comment: Please see the edit, I forgot to mention `GetMode` is static

Comment: OK, it's clear that you're not pasting in your actual code. There has to be something else in your code that is causing this. Can you create a fully-functional sample that demonstrates the problem? What you've posted (still) works perfectly.

Comment: Okay, I'll make a test case

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is that you're either 1) setting the `mimedictionary` reference to null somewhere or 2) there's a separate reference called `mimedictionary` somewhere in the declaration space of `GetMode()` that's not being initialized.  What if you declare `mimedictionary` as `private static readonly`?

Comment: Related reading: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx

Comment: You have a duplicate key. This causes initialization to fail.

Comment: The extension ".tex" appears twice in your long version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding a key to your dictionary more than once, which is causing the static initializer to throw an exception.  You can determine this by examining the `InnerException` property of the exception that is thrown.

Comment: Solved, it's the `.tex`. Thanks for everyone's help, Happy Christmas.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely just a debugger artifact. The runtime may delay initialization of static fields until they're actually needed. Just viewing the field in the debugger doesn't trigger that initialization, so the debugger can observe uninitialized fields which the program itself doesn't observe.

If your class has a static constructor, it's even forced to delay all static initialization until you either instantiate the class, access a static field, or call a static method.

I'm pretty sure that your code won't see `mimedictionary == null`. You can add a `Debug.Assert(mimedictionary!=null)` and you'll see that it doesn't get triggered.

---

Another possibility that can cause trouble is building some circular calls in your initializer. But your code as posted doesn't have this property.

Comment: +1. Yes. See [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx). The text says: "The program cannot specify exactly when the class is loaded. However, it is guaranteed to be loaded and to have its fields initialized and its static constructor called before the class is referenced for the first time in your program."

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes With such subtle points you should look at the spec, and not at MSDN which is often badly worded or missing important details. For example "referenced for the first time" is pretty unclear, and the exact semantics depend on the presence of absence of a static constructor.

Comment: Yes, but the spec must be downloaded and cannot quickly be googeled.

Comment: The spec says "If a static constructor (§10.12) exists in the class, execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that static constructor. Otherwise, the static field initializers are executed **at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static field** of that class." and "[...] when a class is initialized, all static fields in that class are first initialized to their default values, and then the static field initializers are executed in textual order."

Comment: And also "It is not possible to observe the value of a field before this default initialization has occurred, and a field is thus never “uninitialized”".

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Note that "default initialization" mean initialization to `default(T)` and not the initializer having run. There are weird corner cases with circular calls.

Comment: Yes and the order in which static/instance constructors are called can be very puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the problem. The dictionary is filled and contains 9 entries in my tests. The problem is your argument "filename.cpp" that is not a key in the dictionary. And ".cpp" is not contained either. It works if you call with ".cf" for instance.

Use this code if you want to apply it to filenames as well:

```
public static string GetMode(string fileOrExt)
{
    string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileOrExt);
    if (ext == String.Empty) {
        ext = fileOrExt;
        if (!ext.StartsWith(".")) {
            ext = "." + ext;
        }
    }
    Info info;
    if (mimedictionary.TryGetValue(ext, out info)) {
        return info.Mode;
    }
    return "-";
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I would suggest you create a static constructor and initialize all your static types there like in the following example:

```
public class AcmeMimeInfo
{
    private static List<string> list;
    static AcmeMimeInfo()
    {
        list = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this with the dictionary - setting the dictionary up from within the `static` constructor but it didn't work.

Comment: I tried your program and it works as expected.

Comment: (In my initial answer I missed out the parens after the static constructor call.) I did the same changes... making `GetMode` static and initialising the dictionary from the static constructor and the program works on my end. I'm using VS2010.